# Texture doesn't work - OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I don't know why but my code doesn't run any texture. Can someone tell me how to fix it ?

I'm using a function to load the texture and return the GLuint to a variable and set this variable in the object.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <gl/glut.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

float _angle = 0.0;
int zoomX = 0, zoomY=0;

GLuint texturaGrama;
GLfloat angle, fAspect, rotX, rotY, obsZ;

GLuint LoadTexture( const char * filename, int width, int height ){

    GLuint texture;

    unsigned char * data;

    FILE * file;

    file = fopen( filename, "rb" );

    if ( file == NULL ) return 0;
    data = (unsigned char *)malloc( width * height * 3 );
    fread( data, width * height * 3, 1, file );
    fclose( file );

    for(int i = 0; i < width * height ; ++i)
    {
        int index = i*3;
        unsigned char B,R;
        B = data[index];
        R = data[index+2];

        data[index] = R;
        data[index+2] = B;
    }

    glGenTextures( 1, &texture );
    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture );
    glTexEnvf( GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE,GL_MODULATE );
    glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST );


    glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR );
    glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,GL_REPEAT );
    glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,GL_REPEAT );
    gluBuild2DMipmaps( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 3, width, height,GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data );
    free( data );

    return texture;
}
void Desenha(void)
    {
         glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
         glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
         glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
         glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

        // Grama
        glPushMatrix();
            glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

            glTranslatef(0,0,-6);
            glRotatef(_angle, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
            glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texturaGrama);
            glBegin(GL_QUADS);
                glTexCoord2f(0.0f,0.0f);  glVertex3f(-50,-1.5,50);
                glTexCoord2f(1.0f,0.0f);  glVertex3f(-50,-1.5,-50);
                glTexCoord2f(1.0f,1.0f);  glVertex3f(50,-1.5,-50);
                glTexCoord2f(0.0f,0.0f);  glVertex3f(50,-1.5,50);
            glEnd();
            glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    }

    void PosicionaObservador(void)
{
    // Especifica sistema de coordenadas do modelo
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    // Inicializa sistema de coordenadas do modelo
    glLoadIdentity();
    DefineIluminacao();
    // Especifica posição do observador e do alvo
    glTranslatef(zoomX,zoomY,-obsZ);
    glRotatef(rotX,1,0,0);
    glRotatef(rotY,0,1,0);
}

void Inicializa (void)
{
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(-1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0);

    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    texturaGrama = LoadTexture("grass.bmp", 256, 256);

    angle=50;
    rotX = 30;
    rotY = 0;
    obsZ = 10;
}
static void resize(int width, int height)
{
    const float ar = (float) width / (float) height;
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glFrustum(-ar, ar, -1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 100.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    PosicionaObservador();
}


int main(void)
{
     glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH);
     glutInitWindowSize(800,600);
     glutInitWindowPosition(50,50);
     glutCreateWindow("Casa Sinistra");
     glutDisplayFunc(Desenha);
     glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
     glutSpecialFunc(MovimentoTela);
     glutReshapeFunc(resize);
     Inicializa();
     glutMainLoop();
}
```

I have tried many other libs but none of them works. I'm running this code in CodeBlocks with Windows 10. The code runs but the texture doesn't appear. It's happening because of Windows ?
I need to add any library?

Comment: Have you tried `glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_REPLACE);`? You are btw using the OpenGL fixed function pipeline which is deprecated for a decade now. You should consider moving to modern OpenGL.

Comment: Do you have some code example or a website with some better way to do it? I'm newbie with OpenGL.

Comment: At least [`glutInit`](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node10.html) and [`glutSwapBuffers`](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node21.html) is missing in this code.

Comment: I suggest you look at another tutorial. Any tutorial with glBegin and glEnd can not be up to date

Answer (score 2):

The [GLUT library](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/) has to be initilized by [`glutInit`](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node10.html).

Initialize glut at the begin of the program, before you use any instruction of the library:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
     glutInit(&argc, argv); // <------------

     glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH);
     glutInitWindowSize(800,600);
     glutInitWindowPosition(50,50);
     glutCreateWindow("Casa Sinistra");

     .....
```

Since you are using a double buffered window

```
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);
```

you have to call [`glutSwapBuffers`](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node21.html) at the end of the rendering loop (last statement in the loop), to perform a buffer swap for the current window:

```
void Desenha(void)
{
    ......

    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

---

By the way there is a mistake in your texture coordinates, because the uv coordinate (0, 0) is twice (`glTexCoord2f(0.0f,0.0f)`).

Comment: If I add glutSwapBuffers(); after the rendering scene nothing happens but if I add after the glEnd();  the scene bug. Could be because of the glTexCoord2f(); ?